# Decimal format class problems

Tags: java, string, parsing, decimalformat

I have a string and im trying to format it into a decimal format so that there is a , every 3 numbers using the decimal format class but im having troble.  Here is my code

```
 public String getNum()


 {
     //turn the string myNum into a formatted number so there's a , after every 3 digits
      DecimalFormat formNum = new DecimalFormat(myNum "000,000");
     //set formNum to a string don't know what method to use for this step
      return formNum ;
  }
```

myNum is from a text document and is the number 6486  in this instance but in others using the same code it gets all the way up to 301122. With this method I want to turn these numbers into things such as 6,486 or 301,112 my constructor statement my IDE is telling my in it that ")"is expected I'm also not sure how to change my decimal format back into a string once I format my number.

Comment: Did you read the API? Did you check out the links found under the "Related" heading on the ride side of this page?

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to do the DecimalFormat(String pattern) constructor I found in the API but i'm having trouble figuring out why it wont work

Comment: The API has example code.  The answers on the right have example code. Why would the code we type here be any different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a comma there after the myNum. Also, it should be

```
DecimalFormat formNum = new DecimalFormat("000,000");
return formNum.format(myNum);
```

Comment: Putting a comma in says that there is no suitable constructor found

Comment: DecimalFormat doesn't have a constructor for (String, String). @Alex Chapp, use the API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html. There's examples of how to use the class listed there.

Comment: Yes, I was confused myself there for a while, changed the answer

Comment: Now when I run the program it tells me I can't format the given object as a number and I'm not sure why

Comment: @AlexChapp, neither do we know why it doesn't work. We don't have access to your code. We are not mind readers. Don't keep coming back to the forum every time you encounter a little problem. Do some problem solving yourself. We can't guess what your code looks like. The least you can do is post a proper SSCCE, instead of saying "it doesn't work"!!!

Comment: Ok sorry about that ill be more patient with trying to find the answer for a while before asking about It for anyone who looks at this with a similar problem I just figured out the solution is to pass myNum into Decimal Format as an int and not a string using the ParseInt() method before the return statement.